# Three.js: way to change the up axis?

Tags: camera, three.js

I see that the ColladaLoader has a way to set the upAxis to 'Z' ... is there a way to do that in Three.js proper so that the camera's up axis is Z?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the camera `up` vector like so:

```
camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
```

Then when you call `camera.lookAt( point )`, it will work as you expect.

Edit: Updated to three.js r.68

Comment: Is there any workaround available so that OrbitControls will accept a change in up?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You would have to rewrite it.

Comment: So I hacked up the OrbitControls.js file so that it now works if you set z as up. I can probably make it even better so that it changes based on what up is set. Would that be helpful?

Comment: You would have to file a pull request at the three.js github site to find out.

Comment: `TrackballControls` seem to work well with `z` as up out of the box in r62. http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html

Comment: @z0r I tested `TrackballControls`. As far as I tested, it doesn't work good with `camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 )`