# Three JS: Orbit Controls and camera.up.set

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get Orbit Controls to work when I set the camera to :

```
camera.up.set(0,0,1)
```

This ends up not orbiting properly, and some unanswered questions out there call out the issue: [Three.js: way to change the up axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480910/three-js-way-to-change-the-up-axis)

Can anyone provide information for how to change the rotation axis of the orbit?

Comment: see here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4375

This is still an issue!

Comment: You should probably go with another control-module or rotate/import your scene so that you can use Orbit Controls.

Answer (score 4):

This was [recently fixed](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/4530) . If you get the latest three.js dev version from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev , you can just set `camera.up` and OrbitControls will behave accordingly.